# GIT clone issue in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am getting below issue in Jenkins git clone:

> *15:18:02 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   
> 15:18:02 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'*

I tried to manually cloning on the server and got below error:

> (gnome-ssh-askpass:25670): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
>   error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'

I ran below command on server and cloned manually and it was working properly.

> unset SSH_ASKPASS

I set "unset SSH_ASKPASS" in .bash_profile and tried to run from jenkins again, but got the same error. Same is the case with envInject plugin.
Jenkins is creating issue while doing clone freshly. It is working for fetching updated data on existed workspace.

I am using below version of plugins:

> Jenkins: 1.580.3
>   
> GIT Plugin: 2.3.4
>   
> GIT Client Plugin: 1.15.0
>   
> Git client version on server: 1.9.3

Comment: What command did you use for the manual cloning on the server? that Gtk-WARNING is odd.

Comment: git clone <Repository_URL>

Comment: Are you using ssh or https? You may be missing some credentials. Try ssh with id_rsa.pub key.

Comment: How do you do the clone in jenkins? Through some plugin or do you have a Jenkins script?

Comment: I am cloning using jenkins git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Error containing 'origin' often refers to a git remote configuration error: e.g. you're running jenkins on unprivileged user with no .git configurations in his home.

Comment: We are running jenkins with a dedicated user, and it has .gitconfig file in it's home directory.